# PowerShell Connect to FTP server and get files

Tags: powershell, ftp

```
$ftpServer = "ftp.example.com"
$username ="validUser"
$password ="myPassword"
$localToFTPPath = "C:\ToFTP"
$localFromFTPPath = "C:\FromFTP"
$remotePickupDir = "/Inbox"
$remoteDropDir = "/Outbox"
$SSLMode = [AlexPilotti.FTPS.Client.ESSLSupportMode]::ClearText
$ftp = new-object "AlexPilotti.FTPS.Client.FTPSClient"
$cred = New-Object System.Net.NetworkCredential($username,$password)
$ftp.Connect($ftpServer,$cred,$SSLMode) #Connect
$ftp.SetCurrentDirectory($remotePickupDir)
$ftp.GetFiles($localFromFTPPath, $false) #Get Files
```

This is the script I got for importing files from an FTP server.
However I am not sure what is the `remotePickupDir` and is this script correct?

Comment: I'm sorry, but I find all the answers off-track. If powershell was really understood as a shell, you'd just plumb your favorite foolproof native ftp program and be done with it. The sane approach is to have one good tool for one particular task, and that means a feature-rich operating system offering a wide range of command line tools. MS never took that path, and it's still a pain to do the most basic work. Why not swapping your ecosystem by installing cygwin and ncftp?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Remote pick directory path should be the exact path on the ftp server you are tryng to access..
here is the script to download files from the server..
you can add or modify with SSLMode..

```
#ftp server 
$ftp = "ftp://example.com/" 
$user = "XX" 
$pass = "XXX"
$SetType = "bin"  
$remotePickupDir = Get-ChildItem 'c:\test' -recurse
$webclient = New-Object System.Net.WebClient 

$webclient.Credentials = New-Object System.Net.NetworkCredential($user,$pass)  
foreach($item in $remotePickupDir){ 
    $uri = New-Object System.Uri($ftp+$item.Name) 
    #$webclient.UploadFile($uri,$item.FullName)
    $webclient.DownloadFile($uri,$item.FullName)
}
```

Comment: If $remotepickupdir = get-childitem c:\test -recurse, powershell will try to get all items at that path when it sets up the variable. So it can't be retrieving remote items because at this point there hasn't even been a login. Your code looks wrong.

Comment: I got an error from tring `$webclietn.DownloadFile($uri, $item.FullName)` : `Method invocation failed because [System.Net.NetworkCredential] does not contain a method named 'DownloadFile'.`

Answer (score 37):

The AlexFTPS library used in the question seems to be dead (was not updated since 2011).

---

### With no external libraries

You can try to implement this without any external library. But unfortunately, neither the .NET Framework nor PowerShell have any explicit support for downloading all files in a directory (let alone recursive file downloads).

You have to implement that yourself:

- List the remote directory
- Iterate the entries, downloading files (and optionally recursing into subdirectories - listing them again, etc.)

Tricky part is to identify files from subdirectories. There's no way to do that in a portable way with the .NET framework (`FtpWebRequest` or `WebClient`). The .NET framework unfortunately does not support the `MLSD` command, which is the only portable way to retrieve directory listing with file attributes in FTP protocol. See also [Checking if object on FTP server is file or directory](https://stackoverflow.com/q/36895021/850848).

Your options are:

- If you know that the directory does not contain any subdirectories, use the `ListDirectory` method (`NLST` FTP command) and simply download all the "names" as files.
- Do an operation on a file name that is certain to fail for file and succeeds for directories (or vice versa). I.e. you can try to download the "name".
- You may be lucky and in your specific case, you can tell a file from a directory by a file name (i.e. all your files have an extension, while subdirectories do not)
- You use a long directory listing (`LIST` command = `ListDirectoryDetails` method) and try to parse a server-specific listing. Many FTP servers use *nix-style listing, where you identify a directory by the `d` at the very beginning of the entry. But many servers use a different format. The following example uses this approach (assuming the *nix format)

```
function DownloadFtpDirectory($url, $credentials, $localPath)
{
    $listRequest = [Net.WebRequest]::Create($url)
    $listRequest.Method =
        [System.Net.WebRequestMethods+Ftp]::ListDirectoryDetails
    $listRequest.Credentials = $credentials
    
    $lines = New-Object System.Collections.ArrayList

    $listResponse = $listRequest.GetResponse()
    $listStream = $listResponse.GetResponseStream()
    $listReader = New-Object System.IO.StreamReader($listStream)
    while (!$listReader.EndOfStream)
    {
        $line = $listReader.ReadLine()
        $lines.Add($line) | Out-Null
    }
    $listReader.Dispose()
    $listStream.Dispose()
    $listResponse.Dispose()

    foreach ($line in $lines)
    {
        $tokens = $line.Split(" ", 9, [StringSplitOptions]::RemoveEmptyEntries)
        $name = $tokens[8]
        $permissions = $tokens[0]

        $localFilePath = Join-Path $localPath $name
        $fileUrl = ($url + $name)

        if ($permissions[0] -eq 'd')
        {
            if (($name -ne ".") -and ($name -ne ".."))
            {
                if (!(Test-Path $localFilePath -PathType container))
                {
                    Write-Host "Creating directory $localFilePath"
                    New-Item $localFilePath -Type directory | Out-Null
                }

                DownloadFtpDirectory ($fileUrl + "/") $credentials $localFilePath
            }
        }
        else
        {
            Write-Host "Downloading $fileUrl to $localFilePath"

            $downloadRequest = [Net.WebRequest]::Create($fileUrl)
            $downloadRequest.Method =
                [System.Net.WebRequestMethods+Ftp]::DownloadFile
            $downloadRequest.Credentials = $credentials

            $downloadResponse = $downloadRequest.GetResponse()
            $sourceStream = $downloadResponse.GetResponseStream()
            $targetStream = [System.IO.File]::Create($localFilePath)
            $buffer = New-Object byte[] 10240
            while (($read = $sourceStream.Read($buffer, 0, $buffer.Length)) -gt 0)
            {
                $targetStream.Write($buffer, 0, $read);
            }
            $targetStream.Dispose()
            $sourceStream.Dispose()
            $downloadResponse.Dispose()
        }
    }
}
```

Use the function like:

```
$credentials = New-Object System.Net.NetworkCredential("user", "mypassword") 
$url = "ftp://ftp.example.com/directory/to/download/"
DownloadFtpDirectory $url $credentials "C:\target\directory"
```

The code is translated from my C# example in [C# Download all files and subdirectories through FTP](https://stackoverflow.com/q/37038676/850848).

---

### Using 3rd party library

If you want to avoid troubles with parsing the server-specific directory listing formats, use a 3rd party library that supports the `MLSD` command and/or parsing various `LIST` listing formats. And ideally with a support for downloading all files from a directory or even recursive downloads.

For example with [WinSCP .NET assembly](https://winscp.net/eng/docs/library) you can download whole directory with a single call to [`Session.GetFiles`](https://winscp.net/eng/docs/library_session_getfiles):

```
# Load WinSCP .NET assembly
Add-Type -Path "WinSCPnet.dll"

# Setup session options
$sessionOptions = New-Object WinSCP.SessionOptions -Property @{
    Protocol = [WinSCP.Protocol]::Ftp
    HostName = "ftp.example.com"
    UserName = "user"
    Password = "mypassword"
}

$session = New-Object WinSCP.Session

try
{
    # Connect
    $session.Open($sessionOptions)

    # Download files
    $session.GetFiles("/directory/to/download/*", "C:\target\directory\*").Check()
}
finally
{
    # Disconnect, clean up
    $session.Dispose()
}
```

Internally, WinSCP uses the `MLSD` command, if supported by the server. If not, it uses the `LIST` command and supports dozens of different listing formats.

The [`Session.GetFiles` method](https://winscp.net/eng/docs/library_session_getfiles) is recursive by default.

*(I'm the author of WinSCP)*

Answer (score 12):

Here is the full working code to download all files (with wildcard or file extension) from the FTP site to local directory. Set the variable values.

```
    #FTP Server Information - SET VARIABLES
    $ftp = "ftp://XXX.com/" 
    $user = 'UserName' 
    $pass = 'Password'
    $folder = 'FTP_Folder'
    $target = "C:\Folder\Folder1\"

    #SET CREDENTIALS
    $credentials = new-object System.Net.NetworkCredential($user, $pass)

    function Get-FtpDir ($url,$credentials) {
        $request = [Net.WebRequest]::Create($url)
        $request.Method = [System.Net.WebRequestMethods+FTP]::ListDirectory
        if ($credentials) { $request.Credentials = $credentials }
        $response = $request.GetResponse()
        $reader = New-Object IO.StreamReader $response.GetResponseStream() 
        while(-not $reader.EndOfStream) {
            $reader.ReadLine()
        }
        #$reader.ReadToEnd()
        $reader.Close()
        $response.Close()
    }

    #SET FOLDER PATH
    $folderPath= $ftp + "/" + $folder + "/"

    $files = Get-FTPDir -url $folderPath -credentials $credentials

    $files 

    $webclient = New-Object System.Net.WebClient 
    $webclient.Credentials = New-Object System.Net.NetworkCredential($user,$pass) 
    $counter = 0
    foreach ($file in ($files | where {$_ -like "*.txt"})){
        $source=$folderPath + $file  
        $destination = $target + $file 
        $webclient.DownloadFile($source, $target+$file)

        #PRINT FILE NAME AND COUNTER
        $counter++
        $counter
        $source
    }
```

Comment: I keep getting Exception calling "GetResponse" with "0" argument(s): "The remote server returned an error: (530) Not logged in."But when i use the same credentials with flashfxp, regular ftp in explorer or any other client the credentials are fine. Do you know why?

Answer (score 1):

The `remotePickupDir` would be the folder you want to go to on the ftp server.  As far as "is this script correct", well, does it work?  If it works then it's correct.  If it does not work, then tell us what error message or unexpected behaviour you're getting and we'll be better able to help you.

Answer (score 1):

Based on [Why does FtpWebRequest download files from the root directory? Can this cause a 553 error?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61109140/why-does-ftpwebrequest-download-files-from-the-root-directory-can-this-cause-a), I wrote a PowerShell script that enabled to download a file from a FTP-Server via explicit FTP over TLS:

```
# Config
$Username = "USERNAME"
$Password = "PASSWORD"
$LocalFile = "C:\PATH_TO_DIR\FILNAME.EXT"
#e.g. "C:\temp\somefile.txt"
$RemoteFile = "ftp://PATH_TO_REMOTE_FILE"
#e.g. "ftp://ftp.server.com/home/some/path/somefile.txt"

try{ 
    # Create a FTPWebRequest
    $FTPRequest = [System.Net.FtpWebRequest]::Create($RemoteFile)
    $FTPRequest.Credentials = New-Object System.Net.NetworkCredential($Username,$Password)
    $FTPRequest.Method = [System.Net.WebRequestMethods+Ftp]::DownloadFile
    $FTPRequest.UseBinary = $true
    $FTPRequest.KeepAlive = $false
    $FTPRequest.EnableSsl  = $true
    # Send the ftp request
    $FTPResponse = $FTPRequest.GetResponse()
    # Get a download stream from the server response
    $ResponseStream = $FTPResponse.GetResponseStream()
    # Create the target file on the local system and the download buffer
    $LocalFileFile = New-Object IO.FileStream ($LocalFile,[IO.FileMode]::Create)
    [byte[]]$ReadBuffer = New-Object byte[] 1024
    # Loop through the download

    do {
        $ReadLength = $ResponseStream.Read($ReadBuffer,0,1024)
        $LocalFileFile.Write($ReadBuffer,0,$ReadLength)
    }
    while ($ReadLength -ne 0)
    # Close file
    $LocalFileFile.Close()
}catch [Exception]
{
    $Request = $_.Exception
    Write-host "Exception caught: $Request"
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Invoke-WebRequest can download HTTP, HTTPS, and FTP links.

```
$source = 'ftp://Blah.com/somefile.txt'
$target = 'C:\Users\someuser\Desktop\BlahFiles\somefile.txt'
$password = Microsoft.PowerShell.Security\ConvertTo-SecureString -String 'mypassword' -AsPlainText -Force
$credential = New-Object -TypeName System.Management.Automation.PSCredential -ArgumentList myuserid, $password

# Download
Invoke-WebRequest -Uri $source -OutFile $target -Credential $credential -UseBasicParsing
```

Since the cmdlet uses IE parsing you may need the -UseBasicParsing switch. Test to make sure.

Answer (score 0):

For retrieving files /folder from FTP via powerShell I wrote some functions, you can get even hidden stuff from FTP.

Example for getting all files which are not hidden in a specific folder:

```
Get-FtpChildItem -ftpFolderPath "ftp://myHost.com/root/leaf/" -userName "User" -password "pw" -hidden $false -File
```

Example for getting all folders(also hidden) in a specific folder:

```
Get-FtpChildItem -ftpFolderPath"ftp://myHost.com/root/leaf/" -userName "User" -password "pw" -Directory
```

You can just copy the functions from the following module without needing and 3rd library installing:
https://github.com/AstralisSomnium/PowerShell-No-Library-Just-Functions/blob/master/FTPModule.ps1