# Powershell connect to FTP using script

Tags: powershell, ftp

Simple question, how do I connect to a FTP using a powershell script? I can easily connect to the FTP using the command prompt with something such as:

```
ftp "ip address"
"some username"
"some Password"
```

But when I try to connect to the FTP using the above code in a script I cannot connect, all i see is the prompt asking for username. Is there some kind of method that needs to be used in order to connect after giving the FTP "ip address" in a script?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19059394/powershell-connect-to-ftp-server-and-get-files

Answer (score 0):

I found the answer that i needed using ftp -s:"filewithcommands" probably should have explained a bit more on what i wanted. The below being what is inside "filewithcommands"

```
open
IP address
user
pass
cd "targetdir"
get "file"
quit
```

Comment: This has nothing to do with PowerShell.