# Is it possible to download files during the build pipeline on Azure DevOps?

Tags: build, azure-devops, pipeline, devops

We're starting to use Azure DevOps to build and deploy my application. Currently, we do not upload the application images to our repo. I Would like to know if I could download all the images to the artifact that is going to be generated during the build pipeline.

My yml pipeline :
trigger:
- develop

pool:
  vmImage: 'windows-latest'

variables:
  solution: '**/*.sln'
  buildPlatform: 'Any CPU'
  buildConfiguration: 'Release'

steps:
- task: NuGetToolInstaller@0

- task: NuGetCommand@2
  inputs:
  restoreSolution: '$(solution)'
- task: Npm@1
  inputs:
  command: 'install'
  workingDir: 'applicationFolder/app'
- task: VSBuild@1
  inputs:
  solution: '$(solution)'
  msbuildArgs: '/p:DeployOnBuild=true /p:WebPublishMethod=Package /p:PackageAsSingleFile=true /p:SkipInvalidConfigurations=true /p:PackageLocation="$(build.artifactStagingDirectory)"'
  platform: '$(buildPlatform)'
  configuration: '$(buildConfiguration)'
- task: PublishBuildArtifacts@1
  inputs:
  PathtoPublish: '$(Build.ArtifactStagingDirectory)'
  ArtifactName: 'drop'
  publishLocation: 'Container'

Comment: Do you want to download the images and add them to the artifacts?

Comment: Exactly this. We have all images on a folder. but we do not upload those images to our git repository. We also have the files on an FTP server which I would like to download the images from.

Comment: Do you use Microsoft Hosted agent or Self Hosted agent?

Comment: I'm using a self-hosted Agent. But I may change it for a Microsoft Hosted soon.

Comment: In you self hosted agent you can just copy from the folder, no?

Comment: I'm not sure, because the files are in another server.

Comment: do the images folder as "share folder"

Comment: Maybe I'll be able to access FTP using power shell.

Comment: PowerShell is your solution if you want to download from the FTP

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> Is it possible to download files during the build pipeline on Azure DevOps?

The short answer is yes.

There is no out of box task to download the file from FTP server. Only [FTP Upload task](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/tasks/utility/ftp-upload?view=azure-devops) to upload file to the FTP server not download.

So, to resolve it, we could use powershell scripts to connect to FTP server and download files:

Scripts like:

```
#FTP Server Information - SET VARIABLES
$ftp = "ftp://XXX.com/" 
$user = 'UserName' 
$pass = 'Password'
$folder = 'FTP_Folder'
$target = "C:\Folder\Folder1\"

#SET CREDENTIALS
$credentials = new-object System.Net.NetworkCredential($user, $pass)

function Get-FtpDir ($url,$credentials) {
    $request = [Net.WebRequest]::Create($url)
    $request.Method = [System.Net.WebRequestMethods+FTP]::ListDirectory
    if ($credentials) { $request.Credentials = $credentials }
    $response = $request.GetResponse()
    $reader = New-Object IO.StreamReader $response.GetResponseStream() 
    while(-not $reader.EndOfStream) {
        $reader.ReadLine()
    }
    #$reader.ReadToEnd()
    $reader.Close()
    $response.Close()
}

#SET FOLDER PATH
$folderPath= $ftp + "/" + $folder + "/"

$files = Get-FTPDir -url $folderPath -credentials $credentials

$files 

$webclient = New-Object System.Net.WebClient 
$webclient.Credentials = New-Object System.Net.NetworkCredential($user,$pass) 
$counter = 0
foreach ($file in ($files | where {$_ -like "*.txt"})){
    $source=$folderPath + $file  
    $destination = $target + $file 
    $webclient.DownloadFile($source, $target+$file)

    #PRINT FILE NAME AND COUNTER
    $counter++
    $counter
    $source
}
```

Certificate comes from: [PowerShell Connect to FTP server and get files](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19059394/powershell-connect-to-ftp-server-and-get-files).

Then publish those download files to the Artifacts by the task `PublishBuildArtifacts`.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Hello. I get the following error on this script: You cannot call a method on a null-valued expression.
At C:\ftptest.ps1:18 char:9
+         $reader.ReadLine()
+         ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidOperation: (:) [], RuntimeException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : InvokeMethodOnNull

Comment: I made it work now. Do you know how i can get all folder and files in a certain folder?

Comment: How can i make the files save in C:\Folder\Folder1 (or any other path) be published to the artifact using PublishBuildArtifacts?