# Is it possible to download files/data during the build pipeline on Azure DevOps?

Tags: amazon-web-services, azure, azure-devops

We would like to transfer the development via [azure devops](https://azure.microsoft.com/de-de/services/devops/) to another company and we ask ourselves whether not only new releases can be pushed through this pipeline. But also data could be downloaded from the productive environment via the azure devops or aws devops pipeline?
I researched myself but found nothing about it.

does any of you have more information on this?

Thank you

Comment: Please check whether answers below can help you and feel free to comment. If you don't want to download files/data from FTP server. You can edit your question and give more details about want you want to do.

Comment: Hi there, is there any updates for this issue? Have you solved your question?

Answer (score 1):

> Is it possible to download files/data during the build pipeline on Azure DevOps?

In Azure DevOps, there isn't a task to download files/data, but you can use the PowerShell task to connect to FTP server and download files.

For detailed information, you can refer to this [similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56633042/is-it-possible-to-download-files-during-the-build-pipeline-on-azure-devops).

> ```
> - task: PowerShell@2
>   inputs:
>     targetType: 'inline'
>     script: |
>       #FTP Server Information - SET VARIABLES
>       $ftp = "ftp://XXX.com/" 
>       $user = 'UserName' 
>       $pass = 'Password'
>       $folder = 'FTP_Folder'
>       $target = "C:\Folder\Folder1\"
>       
>       #SET CREDENTIALS
>       $credentials = new-object System.Net.NetworkCredential($user, $pass)
>       
>       function Get-FtpDir ($url,$credentials) {
>           $request = [Net.WebRequest]::Create($url)
>           $request.Method = [System.Net.WebRequestMethods+FTP]::ListDirectory
>           if ($credentials) { $request.Credentials = $credentials }
>           $response = $request.GetResponse()
>           $reader = New-Object IO.StreamReader $response.GetResponseStream() 
>           while(-not $reader.EndOfStream) {
>               $reader.ReadLine()
>           }
>           #$reader.ReadToEnd()
>           $reader.Close()
>           $response.Close()
>       }
>       
>       #SET FOLDER PATH
>       $folderPath= $ftp + "/" + $folder + "/"
>       
>       $files = Get-FTPDir -url $folderPath -credentials $credentials
>       
>       $files 
>       
>       $webclient = New-Object System.Net.WebClient 
>       $webclient.Credentials = New-Object System.Net.NetworkCredential($user,$pass) 
>       $counter = 0
>       foreach ($file in ($files | where {$_ -like "*.txt"})){
>           $source=$folderPath + $file  
>           $destination = $target + $file 
>           $webclient.DownloadFile($source, $target+$file)
>       
>           #PRINT FILE NAME AND COUNTER
>           $counter++
>           $counter
>           $source
>       }
> ```
>
> Certificate comes from: [PowerShell Connect to FTP server and get files](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19059394/powershell-connect-to-ftp-server-and-get-files).

Answer (score 0):

You should use [artifacts](https://azure.microsoft.com/de-de/services/devops/artifacts/) when it is inside your "environment".

Otherwise you can use the **normal** command line tools like `git` or `curl` and `wget` this depends on your build agent.