# Why does FtpWebRequest download files from the root directory? Can this cause a 553 error?

Tags: .net, powershell, ftp, ftpwebrequest

I have built a PowerShell script for downloading files from a FTP server. This script is working with all the servers I have tested with expect one. For this one server the script is able to connect, get the directory listing, but each time it attempts to download a file a "553 File Unavailable" error is returned. Below is the code I am using to download files.

```
function Get-FtpFile
{
    Param ([string]$fileUrl, $credentials, [string]$destination)
    try
    {
        $FTPRequest = [System.Net.FtpWebRequest]::Create($fileUrl)
        if ($credentials) 
        {
            $FTPRequest.Credentials = $credentials
        }
        $FTPRequest.Method = [System.Net.WebRequestMethods+Ftp]::DownloadFile
        $FTPRequest.UseBinary = $true
        $FTPRequest.UsePassive = $true

        # Send the ftp request
        $FTPResponse = $FTPRequest.GetResponse()

        # Get a download stream from the server response
        $ResponseStream = $FTPResponse.GetResponseStream()

        # Create the target file on the local system and the download buffer
        $LocalFile = New-Object IO.FileStream ($destination,[IO.FileMode]::Create)
        [byte[]]$ReadBuffer = New-Object byte[] 1024

        # Loop through the download
        do {
            $ReadLength = $ResponseStream.Read($ReadBuffer,0,1024)
            $LocalFile.Write($ReadBuffer,0,$ReadLength)
        }
        while ($ReadLength -ne 0)

        $ResponseStream.Close()
        $ReadBuffer.clear()
        $LocalFile.Close()
        $FTPResponse.Close()
    }
    catch [Net.WebException]
    {
        return "Unable to download because: $($_.exception)"
    }
}
```

I have also implemented .NET tracing to debug this issue, below is one of the message blocks received when attempting to download a file.

```
System.Net Information: 0 : [7712] FtpWebRequest#33194379::.ctor(ftp://**.**.**.**//record/5DE7D3810004)
System.Net Information: 0 : [7712] FtpWebRequest#33194379::GetResponse(Method=RETR.)
System.Net Information: 0 : [7712] FtpControlStream#18792280 - Created connection from 666.66.66.66:61255 to **.**.**.**:21.
System.Net Information: 0 : [7712] Associating FtpWebRequest#33194379 with FtpControlStream#18792280
System.Net Information: 0 : [7712] FtpControlStream#18792280 - Received response [220 FTP server ready. Username and password required]
System.Net Information: 0 : [7712] FtpControlStream#18792280 - Sending command [USER change]
System.Net Information: 0 : [7712] FtpControlStream#18792280 - Received response [331 Password required.]
System.Net Information: 0 : [7712] FtpControlStream#18792280 - Sending command [PASS ********]
System.Net Information: 0 : [7712] FtpControlStream#18792280 - Received response [230 Login successful. .]
System.Net Information: 0 : [7712] FtpControlStream#18792280 - Sending command [OPTS utf8 on]
System.Net Information: 0 : [7712] FtpControlStream#18792280 - Received response [502 Command not implemented, superfluous at this site.]
System.Net Information: 0 : [7712] FtpControlStream#18792280 - Sending command [PWD]
System.Net Information: 0 : [7712] FtpControlStream#18792280 - Received response [257 "/usr/apt/tesla/config" is the current directory.]
System.Net Information: 0 : [7712] FtpControlStream#18792280 - Sending command [TYPE I]
System.Net Information: 0 : [7712] FtpControlStream#18792280 - Received response [200 Switching to Binary mode.]
System.Net Information: 0 : [7712] FtpControlStream#18792280 - Sending command [PASV]
System.Net Information: 0 : [7712] FtpControlStream#18792280 - Received response [227 Entering Passive Mode (10,40,0,92,254,143)]
System.Net Information: 0 : [7712] FtpControlStream#18792280 - Sending command [RETR /record/5DE7D3810004]
System.Net Information: 0 : [7712] FtpControlStream#18792280 - Received response [553 File unavailable.]
System.Net Information: 0 : [7712] FtpWebRequest#33194379::(Releasing FTP connection#18792280.)
```

I have noticed that `FtpWebRequest` does not CD to the directory it is downloading a file from, and instead downloads that file from the servers root directory (or any path set as the root directory). Could this be why I am encountering 553 errors? If so, is there anyway to CD to the directory you want to download files from?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While rare, indeed, some FTP servers cannot handle absolute paths with the `RETR` command. One has to first `CWD` to the directory and then use `RETR` with file name only. `FtpWebRequest` does not support that. You will have to use another FTP library.

---

You have asked about *my* [WinSCP](https://winscp.net/). Its [.NET library](https://winscp.net/eng/docs/library) does not have an explicit *"change directory"* request either. But it does `CWD` in certain situations, so you can make it do, what you need. It particularly does `CWD` before directory listing. So either you can do an explicit listing of the source directory yourself:

```
$session.ListDirectory("/record")
$session.GetFileToDirectory("/record/5DE7D3810004", "C:\local\path")
```

Or if you want to download all files anyway, you can ask for that and WinSCP will do the listing (and `CWD` along) internally.

```
$session.GetFilesToDirectory("/record/*", "C:\local\path").Check()
```

---

Btw, [WinSCP scripting](https://winscp.net/eng/docs/scripting) has an explicit [`cd` command](https://winscp.net/eng/docs/scriptcommand_cd), so you can use the scripting instead, while it is not so convenient to use from PowerShell as the assembly.

---

Or use yet another library. For example [FluentFTP](https://github.com/robinrodricks/FluentFTP) has [`FtpClient.SetWorkingDirectory`](https://github.com/robinrodricks/FluentFTP/wiki/File-Management).

Comment: Thank you Martin I truly appreciate all the help.